# Extract elements from nested list only using functions from purrr package

Tags: r, purrr

How do I extract elements from a nested list only using the purrr package?  In this case I want to get a vector of intercepts after splitting a data.frame. I have accomplished what I need using lapply(), but I would like to use only functions purrr package.

```
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% 
split(.$cyl) %>%
map(  ~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)) %>%        # shorthand  NOTE: ~ lm  
lapply(function(x) x[[1]] [1]) %>% # extract intercepts  <==is there a purrr function for this line?
as_vector()                               # convert to vector
```

I have tried map() and at_depth() but nothing seemed to work for me.

Comment: How did you try `map`? If you delete the function name `lapply` and replace it with `map` - exact same arguments - it works just fine.

Comment: I found the help page for `map` useful here.  It looks like you can do some short-cut coding compared to `lapply`.  Like `map_dbl(c(1, 1))` for indexing nested lists.

Comment: @Gregor.   Aaaargh!  That's just too obvious.  Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `map` functions have some shorthand coding for indexing nested lists.  A helpful snippet from the help page:

> To index deeply into a nested list, use multiple values; c("x", "y")
>   is equivalent to z[["x"]][["y"]].

So using code for nested indexes along with `map_dbl`, which reduces to a vector, you can simply do:

```
mtcars %>%
    split(.$cyl) %>%
    map(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)) %>%
    map_dbl(c(1, 1))

       4        6        8 
39.57120 28.40884 23.86803
```

I also found this [blog post](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/09/29/purrr-0-1-0/) introducing purrr 0.1.0 useful, as it gave a few more example of the shorthand coding that I ended up using.

Comment: Perfect. This is the best answer for me because it doesn't output those vectors with names as attributes. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

using tidy function from broom

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

cyl_group<-mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
        nest()
        
cyl_lm<-cyl_group %>% mutate(
        mod=map(data,~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x))
) %>% mutate(coef=map(mod,~tidy(.x))) %>% unnest(coef)
cyl_lm
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl data             mod    term      estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <dbl> <list>           <list> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 x 10~ <lm>   (Interce~    28.4      4.18       6.79   1.05e-3
#> 2     6 <tibble [7 x 10~ <lm>   wt           -2.78     1.33      -2.08   9.18e-2
#> 3     4 <tibble [11 x 1~ <lm>   (Interce~    39.6      4.35       9.10   7.77e-6
#> 4     4 <tibble [11 x 1~ <lm>   wt           -5.65     1.85      -3.05   1.37e-2
#> 5     8 <tibble [14 x 1~ <lm>   (Interce~    23.9      3.01       7.94   4.05e-6
#> 6     8 <tibble [14 x 1~ <lm>   wt           -2.19     0.739     -2.97   1.18e-2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>